# HP Radio Port 210 web configuration

Tags: java, wifi, hp-procurve, access-point

We acquired used WiFi system to provide better wlan for the customers in our hostel.

The switch is HP PROCURVE 5406zl and we have 50 or so HP PROCURVE RADIO PORT 210 access points.
I set up the switch and connected a few ap's; pfSense DHCP gives IPs to them ok.
However the web management for the ap is not working. It's an unsigned java applet and Java 8 won't run it, even with the IP address in the Java Configuration Exception List.
Tried to install older versions of Java, and using Chrome/FF/IE, no luck.

Is there a workaround to get the web management work or can the ap's be configured some other way?
No manuals included in the bundle and of course in the time manufactured obviously there was no problems with Java back then.

Hopefully someone has a clue, otherwise we have quite a few obsolet access points :)

FWIW Nmap output:

```
PORT     STATE SERVICE

80/tcp   open  http
443/tcp  open  https
444/tcp  open  snpp
8888/tcp open  sun-answerbook
```

Comment: They can be accessed by telnet or SSH as well as web.

Comment: Neither is responding, at least in their default ports.

Answer (score 0):

The RP210 devices (in my environment, back when we used them) were dumb access points. They did not have their own IP address or any user-configurable settings. They needed to be connected to the appropriate vlan so that the management card in the router/switch of the 5406zl (in your case) would discover them automatically. There was no other way to configure them manually. The default vlan was 2100, as I recall. We changed it to 210 for better interoperability with our multivendor switches.

You are correct about java versions and issues. You will want to get an older version of java and an old browser. I suggest spinning up an VM that can be quarantined from your network that can contain this really, really old (and insecure) software.

While you can do many, many things via the CLI, it will be meaningful to be able to access the WebUI from time to time.